# Callback delegate with value type behaviour

Tags: c#, delegates

Consider the following demo

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyCallBackClass myCallbackInstance = new MyCallBackClass();

        MyDelegate myDelegate = delegate() { /*Do nothing*/ };

        myDelegate += () => { Console.WriteLine("First"); };
        myDelegate += () => { Console.WriteLine("Second"); };

        myCallbackInstance.Callback = myDelegate;

        myDelegate += () => { Console.WriteLine("Third"); };

        myCallbackInstance.InvokeCallback();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

delegate void MyDelegate();

class MyCallBackClass
{
    public MyDelegate Callback { get; set; }

    public void InvokeCallback()
    {
        if (Callback != null)
            Callback();
    }
}
```

Since a delegate is a reference type in C#, as read here [Why are delegates reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905962/why-are-delegates-reference-types) I would expect the reference to the delegate *("Callback")* in my object to point to the same delegate as the reference outside of the object *("myDelegate")*. Much to my surprise, the output of this demo application is:

```
First
Second
```

, the third element added to the delegate (MulticastDelegate) is not invoked by the object.

This is not the behaviour I expect from reference types and it seems to me that the delegate is handled as if it were a value type. Where am I wrong in my assumptions? Why isn't the third delegate-element invoked?

Comment: The post you have linked to already discusses that `Delegate`s are **immutable** reference types. Just like `System.String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `someDelegate += someOtherDelegate;` does not modify either delegate.  Instead, it constructs a new delegate which contains all of the methods that were present in the originals, and stores that new delegate into `someDelegate`; the delegates in question will contain the same methods after the call as they did before.

In your example, `myCallBackInstance.Callback` has stored in it a reference to a delegate containing two methods.  The variable `myDelegate` will then have stored in it a reference to a delegate containing three methods.  The latter assignment has no effect upon the earlier-created two-method delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates, while reference types, are immutable.  The `+=` operator doesn't mutate the value of the delegate (as doing so is impossible) rather it creates a new delegate that represents the old delegate combined with the new one and then assigns that new delegate to the variable that the += operator is used on.