# If System.Enum is a class, how can it also be a ValueType?

Tags: c#

System.ValueType is a class, and everything that derives from it is a value type and therefore can't be a class, because classes are reference types.

How is it then possible that System.Enum (which inherits System.ValueType) is defined as a class?

Comment: Because the people who wrote C# make the rules :)

Comment: I think that System.Enum has to be defined as a class in order to be inheritable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324224/why-system-enum-is-not-a-value-type for more information. (I realize that this does not answer your question, but it seems relevant.)

Comment: @David: Actually, no...  The people who wrote .NET make this rule.  C# is one compiler of many that implement those rules in a concrete language.

Comment: @EricJ. You win. I was just being facetious but you are correct. :)

Comment: So is it true to say:
"Everything derived from System.ValueType is a value type, except for System.Enum, which is a reference type, because it is defined as a class."
?

Comment: You've stated that (1) everything that derives from ValueType is a value type, (2) Enum derives from ValueType and (3) Enum is not a value type.  Since those three statements are contradictory, at least one of those statements is wrong. (It's the first one.)

Comment: @user2063755: Eric Lippert should really know... click on his name above to view his profile to find out why :-)

Answer (score 2):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx

> Although ValueType is the implicit base class for value types, you
>   cannot create a class that inherits from ValueType directly. Instead,
>   individual compilers provide a language keyword or construct (such as
>   struct in C# and Structure…End Structure in Visual Basic) to support
>   the creation of value types.

In response to your questions:

> so is it wrong to say that all classes are reference types?

Any class you declare is going to be a reference type.  So I don't think it's wrong to think of all classes as reference types.  It's impossible to create a value type that is declared as a class.  You have to use the struct keyword.  If you try to emulate what you see in the enum class:

```
  public class Test: ValueType
  {
      public string Text { get; set; }
  }
```

...you will get the error 'Test' cannot derive from special class 'System.ValueType'.  I don't know what kind of magic is at work that makes the "ValueType" class special, but as far as I know all .NET languages require you to use a special keyword such as `struct` to define your own value types.  It is confusing, but probably serves important purposes such as gracefully handling boxing/unboxing, reflection(.IsValueType?), and similar things.

> if you have an abstract class, you can't instantiate it, so it will
>   never go on the heap, ie. won't act like a reference type?

Yes, but this is totally different from ValueTypes.  You can declare a ValueType like int, assign values to it, pass it around, it can be unboxed and boxed.  None of these things works for an abstract class alone.

As the name implies, it is an **abstraction** for some other concrete class.  When you declare a variable of type SomeAbstractClass, **you can't do anything with it until you initialize its reference to some concrete class inheriting that abstract class**.  Hence, every operation/interaction with that variable will be happening against the concrete class(although it might leverage some of the implementation in the abstract class).  So anytime you are working with an abstract class variable, you are really working with a concrete class, and thus **it is still a reference type and all the things like heap apply to it just like any other reference type**.

Comment: so is it wrong to say that all classes are reference types?
ie. if you have an abstract class, you can't instantiate it, so it will never go on the heap, ie. won't act like a reference type?

Answer (score 2):

Everything in .NET derives from System.Object:

> Both reference and value types are derived from the ultimate base class Object. In cases where it is necessary for a value type to behave like an object, a wrapper that makes the value type look like a reference object is allocated on the heap, and the value type's value is copied into it. The wrapper is marked so the system knows that it contains a value type. This process is known as boxing, and the reverse process is known as unboxing. Boxing and unboxing allow any type to be treated as an object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: One point of potential confustion, `int` and `Int32` are the same thing, `int` is just a C# alias for `Int32`.  I used to think `int` was the value type and `Int32` was the boxed class, but that is not true.  They are both the same thing and are both ValueTypes.

Comment: The ECMA spec regards each value-type definition as defining a storage-location type and a wrapper-object type.  The wrapper-object behaves like a derivative of `System.Object` (since it is one), and exhibits reference semantics; the storage-location type does neither.  The idea that "everything" is a derivative of "object" is a leaky and IMHO unhelpful abstraction.