# C# 7.3 Enum constraint: Why can't I use the nullable enum?

Tags: c#, enums, roslyn, c#-7.3

Now that we have enum constraint, why doesn't compiler allow me to write this code?

```
public static TResult? ToEnum<TResult>(this String value, TResult? defaultValue)
    where TResult : Enum
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? defaultValue : (TResult?)Enum.Parse(typeof(TResult), value);
}
```

The compiler says:

> Error CS0453 The type 'TResult' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

Comment: `System.Enum` inherits from `System.ValueType` so I expect it to be a value not a class.

Comment: @mjwills it's worth noting that a class cannot be Nullable because it's a reference type (which can be null). Nullable is reserved for value types which are distinctly different to the ValueType class that Enum inherits from.

Comment: @DanielleSummers At least until C#8 where we get nullable reference types...

Comment: This seems like a serious flaw in the implementation of this new generic constraint. I would expect it to not refer to the `System.Enum` class specifically, but rather just types defined with the `enum` keyword, which are always value types. I would post this as a bug on the C# github, if it's not already there.

Comment: @DavidG - meanwhile I'm still waiting for non-nullable reference types...

Comment: @Corak That's the same thing really

Comment: @JamesFaix It's not really supposed to be a new generic constraint. It's the same constraint that has always been valid in CIL but has been artificially restricted in C# until 7.3. Because of that, I don't expect it to be useful to report it as a bug.

Comment: `I would expect it to not refer to the System.Enum class specifically, but rather just types defined with the enum keyword` Why would you expect that? When other types are mentioned in constraints does it only allow types that inherit from it? Or also the type itself?

Comment: @KirillKovalenko: `System.Enum` is a [special class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961823/what-exactly-is-a-special-class)(which can't be used as type parameter constraint anyway). It is so special that it inherits from `System.ValueType` but is a reference type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561338/enum-is-reference-type-or-value-type

Comment: @mjwills Because the `Enum` base class is a weird case in the .NET type hierarchy, and all classes that inherit from it are value types. I thought the new constraint was akin to the `class` or `struct` constraints, not just allowing a base class constraint that was forbidden before.

Comment: I started with the same (incorrect) assumption and ended up using `struct, Enum`. See my question [Why is a generic type constrained by 'Enum' failing to qualify as a 'struct'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294032/why-is-a-generic-type-constrained-by-enum-failing-to-qualify-as-a-struct)

Comment: What an absolutely useless feature.  You can constrain the type to `Enum`, but you can't do anything with it!  You can't cast it to 'int', you can't combine flags with `|`.  These all give errors: `TEnum val; var i = (int)val; //ERROR: "Cannot convert type 'TEnum' to 'int'"` or `TEnum a, b; var c = a | b; //ERROR: "Operator '|' cannot be applied to type 'TEnum' and 'TEnum'."`  Useless.

Comment: @Triynko That is irrelevant for this question - please ask your own question if you are interested in discussing that specific issue.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can, but you have to add another constraint: the `struct` constraint.

```
public static void DoSomething<T>(T? defaultValue) where T : struct, Enum
{
}
```

Comment: That isn't a workaround. It is just what the specs tell us to do @KirillKovalenko

Comment: @PatrickHofman Can you link to the specs?  I must have missed that part in my reading.

Comment: Because `Nullable<T>` requires `T` to be a `struct` type @thermite.

Comment: Thanks @patrick, I found it in the docs for nullable. I was looking in the docs at enums and generics...

Comment: @thermite can you link to the doc you found?

Comment: The docs for `Nullable<T>` show the `where T : struct` constraint.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1 .  Here is the constraint in the source code: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs#L27 / https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.0-preview.5.20278.1/src/libraries/System.Runtime/ref/System.Runtime.cs#L2864

Answer (score 20):

Because `System.Enum` is a class, you cannot declare a variable of type `Nullable<Enum>` (since `Nullable<T>` is only possible if `T` is a `struct`).

Thus:

```
Enum? bob = null;
```

won't compile, and neither will your code.

This is definitely strange (since `Enum` itself is a class, but a specific `Enum` that you define in your code is a `struct`) if you haven't run into it before, but it is clearly a `class` (not a `struct`) as per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx) and the source code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374657/if-system-enum-is-a-class-how-can-it-also-be-a-valuetype @Freggar.